# Add pandas dataframe as html in the body on my email

Tags: python, pandas

I have searched for and read multiple supposed solution to this as i know it's very common but nothing is working. I have a dataframe called total_fees and I want to include it in the body of my email. Here is the code to create the email and when i run it i get this error - AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'to_html'.

```
total_fees = dma_fees['DMA_FEE_SUBTOTAL'].sum()
import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'patrick.oneill@example.com'
mail.Subject = 'Example'
mail.Body = "Hi,\n total fees for the previous month were " + str(total_fees)
mail.HTMLBody = """\
    <html>
      <head></head>
      <body>
        <p>Hi<br>
           Fees broken down by product:<br>
           {0}
           <br>Fees broken down by trader:<br>
           {1}
           <br>Fees broken down by broker:<br>
           {2}

           Regards,
           Patrick
        </p>
      </body>
    </html>

    """.format(product_splits.to_html(), trader_splits.to_html(), broker_splits.to_html())
```

Comment: What is `total_fees`?

Comment: can you show us where you declare total fees ?

Comment: total_fees doesn't seem to be a dataframe, so there is no .to_html() method. Maybe you did overwrite the variable name at some point?

Comment: I think total-fees has never been declared

Comment: sorry it was declared but it actually wasn't a dataframe. My mistake. It is just an integer calc'd by summing a column in another dataframe so I mistakenly assumed it would also be a dataframe. In this case I have actually successfully added some other dataframe variables to the above code and it works fine sending the DFs. So what I should have asked originally is how I send the total_fees integer variable in the body of the email. I have amended the code on the original question to show what I have now. The html body gets sent fine but nothing from the mail.Body is included in the email??